# Raspbian QML bad performance

Tags: raspberry-pi, qml

The same QML program run on Freescale/Yocto and Raspberry/Raspbian, these two test devices have almost same CPU `armv7`. But the Raspbain side had very bad performance. and give this warning

```
JIT is disabled for QML. Property bindings and animations will be very slow. 
Visit https://wiki.qt.io/V4 to learn about possible solutions for your platform.
```

Even simple QML example also gives that. So to enable JIT, do I have to rebuild the Qt environment? or it's a bug of Raspbain platform.

Comment: please post the thing that comes after "**Update**" as an answer instead of an edit to you question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to improve the performance:
Enable OpenGL driver solved the problem.

1. Open `raspi-config`
2. `Advanced Options`
3. `GL Driver`
4. `GL(Full KMS)`

Now working well, but still get the `JIT` warning.

Comment: I found that the GL (Full KMS) driver does not appear to work with the "Official" 7" LCD Touchscreen on the Pi (after enabling it, I only get a blank screen). However, the FL (Fake KMS) works fine, and also makes QML apps much faster.

Comment: I don't know if this still useful but I was able to solve your problem @itnAAnti. Maybe this can be helpful to other people. First I set the correct resolution supported by our 7" display which is 800x480 through Preferences -> Raspberry Pi Configuration then reboot. After reboot, I opened, `raspi-config` then Advanced Options -> Resolution -> Default Monitor preferred resolution -> Ok -> Finish then reboot. After the reboot my 7" display is now working.

Comment: also found that Full KMS driver did not work with "Official" 7" screen. Fake KMS seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You must rebuild Qt to get full eglfs or X11/openGL features
and crosscompiling features