# How do I solve the warning 'JIT is disabled for QML. Property bindings and animations will be very slow.' in QT Creator

Tags: ios, qt, ipad, qt-creator

How do I solve the below warning in QT creator.

JIT is disabled for QML. Property bindings and animations will be very slow. Visit https://wiki.qt.io/V4 to learn about possible solutions for your platform.

I am running the QT application in iPad.

As per the [url](https://wiki.qt.io/V4) says I have removed the `Q_OS_IOS` macro. Still the problem exist.

Comment: I have faced the QML performance before in raspberry. and also got the JIT warning. Fixed it by enabling OpenGL driver, so looks like the warning is not the actual problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47899501/raspbian-qml-bad-performance